# qsort creates a non specific number of zeros

Tags: c, zero, qsort

So my program reads integers from a file while skipping lines that start with `#`, stores then in an array and prints them sorted using the `qsort` function. However, when they are printed, at the beginning for some reason it prints a number of zeros and then the sorted numbers. If the pairs of numbers are 60 I get 21 zeros, if the pairs are 103688 it prints 60151 zeros.

The input file:

```
#Skip
#These
#Lines
25  8
25  19
25  23
25  28
25  29
25  30
25  33
25  35
25  50
25  54
25  55
```

The program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;   
} path;

int cmp(const void *a,const void *b){
    int l=((path*)a)->start;
    int r=((path*)b)->start;

    if(l>r)
        return 1;
    if(l<r)
        return -1;
    if(l==r)
        return 0;
}

int doublesize(path** array,int n){
    path* new_array=malloc(n*2*sizeof(path));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_array[i]=(*array)[i];
    }
    free(*array);
    *array=new_array;
    n*=2;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int maxsize=10;
    int test;
    path* array=malloc(maxsize*sizeof(path));
    if(array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    FILE* fd=fopen("Test.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;

    char c;
    while(fgets(buff,200,fd)) {
        c=buff[0];
        if(c=='#') {
            continue;
        }
        sscanf(buff,"%d%d",&array[counter].start,&array[counter].end);
        counter++;
        if(counter==maxsize){
           maxsize=doublesize(&array,maxsize); 
        }
    }
    counter=0;
    qsort(&array[0],maxsize,sizeof(path),cmp);
    for(int i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
        printf("%d\t%d\n",array[i].start,array[i].end);
        if(array[i].start==0)
            counter++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",counter);
    fclose(fd);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the `cmp()` function has a path that does not return a value!  suggest:  `  if(l>r)
        return 1;
    if(l<r)
        return -1;
   else
        return 0;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sorting and then printing `maxsize` elements, when your array only contains `counter` elements (after your first `while` loop). You should use the exact number of elements when sorting and when printing.

The fact that you see a lot of `0` is merely a coincidence. When you allocate space using `malloc()`, the content of your array is *undefined*, meaning that everything that you don't explicitly overwrite will have an undefined value (it could be `0` or it could be another random value). When you sort, all the `0`s will be moved to the beginning, but anything else that was undefined (and not `0`) will actually get in the middle of your data, possibly becoming indistinguishable from real data.

This is not `qsort`'s fault, it's `malloc`'s fault (and really ultimately your fault).

TL;DR: keep a variable holding the *exact number* of elements in the array and never operate after that number.

A quick solution (I've marked the modifications with `^^^`):

```
int total = 0;
//  ^^^^^
int counter = 0;
char c;

while(fgets(buff, 200, fd)) {
    if(buff[0] == '#')
        continue;

    sscanf(buff,"%d%d", &array[counter].start, &array[counter].end);
    total++;
//  ^^^^^

    if(total == maxsize)
//     ^^^^^
        maxsize = doublesize(&array, maxsize);
}

qsort(&array[0], total, sizeof(path), cmp);
//               ^^^^^

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++){
//                 ^^^^^
    printf("%d\t%d\n", array[i].start, array[i].end);

    if(array[i].start == 0)
        counter++;
}
```